# HTML5 page and android webView

Tags: android, html

I have an html page in which I have used two audio tags and loading two files we can mix them using the volume controls, I converted it to an android app using web view , but only one audio play at one time

Is there any solution for this so that my html page loads in web view and we can mix both audio as I do in the html page

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Please read this article on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and take the tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour - You'll need to share some code and more details in order for people to help you.

Comment: is my question not understandable and genuine with out codes ?

Comment: Your question is genuine, but it'll be hard for others to figure it out what's wrong with it without seeing some code.